# Theorem of alternatives for strict generalized inequalities

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis

This is with reference to example 2.26 in Boyd and Vandenberghe's [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook). I am attaching a screenshot below for reference. I don't understand the text highlighted in gray. What is the reason behind the constraint on $\mu$?

[image: Example image]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look closely at:
\begin{equation}
\lambda^T y \geq \mu \; \forall y \in K
\end{equation}
$K$ is a cone so $0\in K$. Set $y=0$ then observe $0\geq \mu$. That also implies $\lambda \in K^*$.